# Vue.js variable undefined after being passed to another component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I have a variable `commentRecId` in component **A**, that I want to pass to use it in component **B**.

I included this in the template of component **A**:

```
<EditComment v-bind:comment-rec-id="commentRecId" v-if="showEdit"></EditComment>
```

I set `showEdit` to true in the methods of component **A**:

```
methods: {
  loadComments: function() {
    this.showEdit = true;
    console.log("this.ShowEdit in ShowComment: " + this.showEdit);
    console.log("commentRecID in ShowComment: " + this.commentRecId);
```

Up until now this works perfectly fine and `commentRecID` does have a value.

The problem is that the variable `commentRecId` is shown as undefined in the other component **B** and after hours of trial and error I still don't understand why.

In component **B**, I have this in the props:

```
export default {
    props: ["commentRecId"],
```

and used this to reference the variable:

```
var statID = this.commentRecId;
console.log("Edit Comment this.commentRecId: " + statID);
```

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

([Component A](https://pastebin.com/ZJw3GRJM))
([Component B](https://pastebin.com/Jjy0XUR8))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `statID` as a computed property use it in the mounted hook :

```
computed :{
  statID (){
   return this.commentRecId;
  }

}
```

and reference it in mounted hook by prefixing it with `this` like `console.log("Edit Comment this.commentRecId: " + this.statID);`

Comment: How do I have to reference statID in mounted?

Comment: You could reference it like `console.log("Edit Comment this.commentRecId: " + this.statID);`

Comment: Hmm, I get a `ReferenceError: statID is not defined
    at a.mounted`

Comment: did you add `this` before it like `this.statID`

Comment: I experimented a bit, now it just says that it's undefined. This is what it looks like after your suggestion: https://pastebin.com/PJrZJ4N6

Comment: Your code is correct as i suggested, i think that mounted hook is ran before computed property, what i suggest is to use the code inside the mounted in a watcher property, check this https://pastebin.com/Gv8n21e6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211397/discussion-between-politics-student-and-boussadjra-brahim).